# Difference between pthread_exit() and exit()?

Tags: c, pthreads

What's the difference between `pthread_exit()` and `exit()`?

Answer (score 6):

Did you read man pages?

`exit()` performs normal program termination, while `pthread_exit()` kills calling thread.

Answer (score 3):

the differences:

pthread_exit(): terminate a thread-whether its work is done or not
exit() perfoms normal program termination for the entire process.

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_exit` terminates a thread. Per [the docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_exit.html)

> Thread termination does not release any application visible process
>   resources, including, but not limited to, mutexes and file
>   descriptors, nor does it perform any process level cleanup actions,
>   including, but not limited to, calling any atexit() routines that may
>   exist.

[`exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/exit.html), on the other hand, does do this.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are created using pthread_create(). Each thread can then independently
terminate using pthread_exit(). (If any thread calls exit(), then all threads immediately terminate.) Unless a thread has been marked as detached (e.g., via a call to
pthread_detach()), it must be joined by another thread using pthread_join(), which
returns the termination status of the joined thread.